# How to create and dial a PPPoE connection in openSUSE 11.2?

Tags: opensuse-11.2, pppoe

How to create and dial a [PPPoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet) connection in [openSUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) 11.2?

Please give step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through YaST. Check out [this thorough guide](http://forums.opensuse.org/new-user-how-faq-read-only/unreviewed-how-faq/387217-default-how-configure-pppoe-broadband-internet-connec.html).